# jQuery image slider with links stops rotator from changing images

Tags: jquery, slider, image-gallery

I've made an image rotator/slide with jQuery which works fine when it's just images, but if I wrap the img tag in an href then the slides won't move past the first image.
I am still fairly new to jQuery, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the img:first/img:visible parts of the code since that looks for the images in the container, rather than the a tag. I've tried wrapping the img tags with a span and assigned the class to be what the code looks for, so whether there is just a image or an image with a link it won't matter, but I can't seem to get that to work (though I'm probably just doing it wrong).

Another thing to note is that the image list is dynamically made with PHP, and if I can get this to work, then the href around the images would be added by PHP if set - so it's not always guaranteed that the images will always be a link or not, or it could be a mixture.

Anyway, here is the code snippet below; also here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLuke/QSj4k/) of it working as it is now without linked images.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slide_wrapper">

    <p id="slide_controls">
        <span id="prev-but"><img src="http://webbossuk.com/admin/JS/webboss-slider/imgs/but_prev.png" alt="Previous" /></span>
        <span id="next-but"><img src="http://webbossuk.com/admin/JS/webboss-slider/imgs/but_next.png" alt="Next" /></span>
    </p>


<div id="image-container">  

    <img class="slide_img" src="http://www.webbossuk.com/uploads/features_banner_shop.jpg" alt="Slide 1" title="" />
    <img class="slide_img" src="http://www.webbossuk.com/uploads/features_banner_podcasts.jpg" alt="Slide 2" title="" />
    <img class="slide_img" src="http://www.webbossuk.com/uploads/features_banner_page_ed.jpg" alt="Slide 3" title="" />
    <img class="slide_img" src="http://www.webbossuk.com/uploads/features_banner_members.jpg" alt="Slide 4" title="" />
    <img class="slide_img" src="http://www.webbossuk.com/uploads/features_banner_more.jpg" alt="Slide 5" title="" />

    <p id="slide_caption"><span></span></p>
</div>

</div>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
var Speed = 5000; //Time in Ms

(function imageTransition() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#image-container img:visible').fadeOut("slow"); // FADE OUT VISIBLE IMAGE
    if ($('#image-container img:visible').next('img').size("slow") < 1) {
        $('#image-container img:first').fadeIn(); // FADE IN FIRST IMAGE    
        $('#slide_caption').html('<span>' + $('#image-container img:first').attr('title') + '</span>');

        if ($('#slide_caption span').html() == "") {
            $('#slide_caption').fadeOut(); //HIDE CAPTION IF NO ALT TEXT
        } else {
            $('#slide_caption').fadeIn();
        }
    } else {
        $('#image-container img:visible').next('img').fadeIn("slow"); // FADE IN NEXT IMAGE    
        $('#slide_caption').html('<span>' + $('#image-container img:visible').next('img').attr('title') + '</span>'); //SHOW ALT TEXT CAPTION
        if ($('#slide_caption span').html() == "") {
            $('#slide_caption').fadeOut(); //HIDE CAPTION IF NO ALT TEXT
        } else {
            $('#slide_caption').fadeIn();
        }
    }

    imageTransition(); //TRIGGER FUNCTION AGAIN
}, Speed); //Xms INTERVAL BEFORE FUNCTION RUNS AGAIN
})();​
```

**-----EDIT-----**

Since a new issue came up from the solution to this one, I've made a new question to deal with that, rather than it all be in the comments below: [jQuery image slider caption issues, displaying wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677389/jquery-image-slider-caption-issues-displaying-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each slide in a div, like this:

```
<div class="slide">
    <a href="http://example.com">
        <img class="slide_img" src="http://www.webbossuk.com/uploads/features_banner_shop.jpg" alt="Slide 1" title="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Then fade out and fade in the divs rather than the images themselves.

Comment: So would I use  $('#image-container .slide:visible').fadeOut("slow"); and  $('#image-container .slide:first').fadeIn(); in place of the current code?

Comment: You could just use $('.slide:visible').fadeOut("slow") and $('.slide:first').fadeIn(). Also, you will need to change each instance of next('img') to next('.slide').

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll give it a try on the fiddle and see how I get on

Comment: Thanks, this answers the problem! The only problem now is the captions overlays don't work (they get the text from the img title) and instead of fading out if blank, just say "undefined" now. You can see here if you can help still? http://jsfiddle.net/MrLuke/QSj4k/27/

Comment: Get the caption with something like this: $('.slide:visible').children('img').attr('title'). Also, move your "if" statement so that you first check to see if the image in the slide has a title attribute. If it does, then set the content of the caption with that title and fade the caption in.

Comment: I've almost got it now.. it's just the first and second caption that messes up and I'm not sure why! I've changed the if statement around and the :visible selector etc to see what makes it change, but can't understand it. You can see here what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLuke/QSj4k/33/

if there's a first caption it shows, but the second will not show, or it will show the 3rd caption in place of 2nd, as well as display it third. It's confusing me

Comment: I would recommend simplifying your code by appending each slide to the end of the div after the slides are faded out. This makes it much easier to control the slideshow because you always fade out the first one. Then, select the image in the slide using .find('img') rather than .children('img') because children will not fetch grandchildren (which the image becomes if it is inside an a tag). Sorry, I think I was the one who suggested using .children() first and that was in error.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to show how this would be accomplished. Note that this required a new div id="slides" to be placed around all the .slide divs. http://jsfiddle.net/dSugW/2/